# Google Play Games Signin cancelled with status code SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am using GoogleSignInClient class for sign in user to my game. I called getSignInIntent with startactivity for Signing in the play games.

```
 Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
  startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

On Activity result it always return requestcode 0(Cancelled) and intent data with StatusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED Resolution=null.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

But it works for my new game.
By updating my old games from Googleapiclient to GoogleSignInClient, I Getting this problem.What I want to do? to get SignIN

Comment: It's hard (or impossible) to tell why it works in you new and not in your old apps given the details in your question. Try comparing the dependencies, the structure and libraries of your apps, surely there's a difference that causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for  your comment,I checked for the differences no changes in that, Additionally  Iam using G+ in this game, did I want to add anything in google console.

Comment: compare. or create a new project with same code logic but new android version, dependency, etc

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments.  The mistake is mine,  I didn't add  my test device's mail id to google console.  As it used debug key for testing,  it returns  SIGNINREQUIRED result.  With released apk SignIn worked. Now I added my device Id, it works fine with debug key also.